# Is there a reason why numpy arrays lose a dimension if the input is a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My preferred method of manually defining a numpy array is to input in a list of tuples after seeing it done so in the numpy's [user guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html). It makes tracking the brackets a little easier:

[image: Numpy User Guide]

But further searching through the documentation I don't know if this is considered the standard, or if there is a specific use case to it. On the whole, they seem to work exactly the same way as inputting in a list of lists except when trying to explicitly define a 2D array. It automatically becomes a 1D array while a list of lists using the same syntax becomes a 2D array.

**In the code below, I would expect `a2` to have the same shape as `b1`.** Is there a reason for them being different?

```
a1 = np.array([1, 1])
print(a1.shape) # (2,)

a2 = np.array([[1], [1]])
print(a2.shape) # (2, 1)

b1 = np.array([(1), (1)])
print(b1.shape) # (2,)

b2 = np.array(((1, 2), (1, -5)))
print(b2.shape) # (2, 2)
```

Comment: `(some_object)` is just a different way to write `some_object`. `(some_object,)` is a tuple with length `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, a one-element tuple actually [requires a comma](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax), not just parenthesis. With out the comma, `(1) == 1`. To get your desired output you need:

```
b1 = np.array([(1,), (1,)])
b1.shape
# (2, 1)
```